# Passing array from useState as prop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-array-from-usestate-as-prop-868kr). I have to sliders and I drag them. Because I have two values I store them in useState as an array.
Then storing as an array the `ComponentsWithArrayAsProp1` doesn't see changes in the state as it is the same array and does not re-render itself.

In the second example, I store values as `values.toString()`, but this is not a good solution.

What is a good solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Then storing as an array the ComponentsWithArrayAsProp1 doesn't see changes in the state as it is the same array and does not re-render itself.*

you are right we can solve it by creating new array everytime as follows,

```
function onChange1(values) {
    setValues1([...values]);
  }
```

but i think there is something wrong with react-slider .because your approach of setting array ,setValues1(values) works when we click on different points of slider1. but it deosn't work when we drag it. there is something else going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

As you said, the `ComponentsWithArrayAsProp1` doesn't see the changes because the array reference is the same, so it doesn't rerender. But you can save a copy of the array instead of the array itself.

```
function onChange1(values) {
  setValues1(values.slice());

  // Another way to do this
  // setValues1([...values]);
}
```

### Option 2:

You can also save the array numbers individually, like so:

```
const [values1Start, setValues1Start] = useState(0);
const [values1End, setValues1End] = useState(0);

function onChange1(values) {
  setValues1Start(values[0]);
  setValues1End(values[1]);
}

return (
  <ComponentsWithArrayAsProp1 values={[values1Start, values1End]} />
);
```